# Can diff message be displayed in comment section of svn commit?

Tags: svn, configuration

Right now my workflow consists of `svn diff | view -` followed by `svn commit`. Now I wonder if there is a way that svn can be configured to show the svn diff output directly below the ignored section with its file list in order to commit directly after verifying the rest.

Comment: Do you want the diff to be part of your commit message? Why would you want to have that? It duplicates information that may be created at any time later ...

Comment: No, the diff output should only be displayed but ignored on commit. I want to ease the work process. Often I hit `svn commit` only to realize I forgot to ´svn diff´. So I thought it would be neat to have it in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the simple command line option of git (git commit -a -v) does not exist in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

by the moment of the commit you should have already reviewed all changes and be sure that you want to commit. If you want to look at the diff while you are composing the commit message, just compose it in a separate file and commit with `svn commit -F`

Comment: Yeah, I know I should. But when I forgot it would be nice to just see the diff already without switching to another console, but instantly see all my changes and commit anyhow if everything is fine.I distinguish between `svn commit` as a maybe and ´svn commit -m "you crazy soab"´ ;)